# WordPress or PHP script to pick an image file from a plugin folder

Tags: php, wordpress, file-browser

I'm creating a WordPress plugin that allows a user to select one of several image files that are distributed with it. Is there a simple technique for allowing the user to view the files in a filebrowser-like interface and pick one? I want it to look as similar as possible to picking a file in the normal file upload dialog.

Comment: are you going to let the user navigate through folders? if not just use a combo box that you filled using scandir.

Comment: There's a possibility that the images shall be organized into subfolders, so yes the user shall be allowed to navigate these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adapting the code from [this filebrowser](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/237790-php-file-browser/) that utilizes scandir. It has a nice simple interface and the code is simple enough to incorporate into a plugin.